# Rust static library "unlinked native library" warnings

Tags: static-libraries, rust

I'm using Rust 0.11-pre to compile a simple staticlib

```
#![crate_type = "staticlib"]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo() {  
}
```

And then I compile with

```
rustc foo.rs --crate-type="staticlib" -o foo.a
```

It's working fine, but I get the following warnings and I'm wondering how to resolve them

```
warning: unlinked native library: System
warning: unlinked native library: c
warning: unlinked native library: m
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: not really sure what's up here. Maybe you could [file a bug](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/new) about the warnings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on something else, and happened to encounter this too: I know what's happening.

A Rust staticlib isn't linked against all its native dependencies. You need to link against those libraries when linking the staticlib into another program, e.g. on Linux, I had to compile `gcc my_c_program.c -L . -lfoo -lc -lpthread -lm -ldl` where `foo.a` was the Rust staticlib (in the current directory) and the last four args are the libraries that had a "unlinked native library" warning (strictly speaking the `-lc` is unnecessary, since the C compiler links against libc by default).

Comment: Interesting, so since it's rustc reporting these warnings there wouldn't be a way to clear them, it's just telling me what I need to link? I bet this explains the crash I saw when accessing task_rng in a static library without linking the native libraries.

Comment: @AJD yes, I think it is just telling you that. However, I'd guess that the `task_rng` "crash" is a "fatal runtime error"? If so, it's because the `task_rng` requires a [runtime](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/guide-runtime.html) to work. You can start one on the current thread using [`native::start`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/native/fn.start.html).

Comment: @AJD, btw this question prompted me [to make the error message clearer](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/14472).